# Transmission seems to go in neutral when I stop or when starting

Tags: transmission, shifting, oldsmobile, bravada

I have a 02 Oldsmobile bravada. It is an automatic transmission. When I start the car or come to a stop it will drop into neutral. If I drop it into 2nd it will go and then I can put it into drive and it drives fine. Someone told me it was probably some boot on the transmission but not sure what it would be called. Anyone help me determine what needs replaced?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the fluid levels in the transmission?

Comment: "Drop into Neutral"  Huh?  Are you telling me when you start or come to a stop, the car transmission lever shifts by itself from Drive to Neutral?  And you have not yet answered Paulster2 question on transmission fluid.  If levels are sound, and without the "drop into neutral" comment this sounds like broken first gear within the transmission, possibly sheared off collar on one of the gears.

Comment: Could be broken motor  or transmission mounts. As the engine shifts during deacceleration it can move the linkage shifting the transmission.

Comment: It stays in drive but if my foot isn’t on the brake it will roll as in neutral and just revs when I give it gas. I put it in 2nd just to get going and then put it back in drive and it’s fine till I stop again. I forgot to mention that my service brake alert came on also and for some reason I can’t get the code reader to work when I try

Comment: I have checked fluids though